# angularjs and ui-router - controller not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[The full source code.](https://github.com/rchampa/AngularJS-Examples/tree/master/ModularDesignExample)

I don't understand why $scope not working in my LoginGuideCtrl controller. I try click on login button and should show a `<p>` with new data but the $scope is not updating...

Don´t forget I'm trying to achieve a modular design.

I have the following code:

## guides.js

```
var guides = angular.module('main.guides',  ['ui.router']).config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.
  state('guides.login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'modules/guides/views/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginGuideCtrl'
  }).

  ...

  state('guides.mobile', {
    url: '/web',
    template: '<div>guildes mobile</div>',
    controller: 'ListCtrl'
  });
});
```

## controller.js

```
var guides = angular.module('main.guides');
guides.controller('IndexCtrl', function() {
    console.log('Index');
})
.controller('LoginGuideCtrl', function($scope) {

  console.log('feck');
  $scope.checkLogin = function(){
    $scope.message = "Welcome "+$scope.name+"!"
  };

})
.controller('ListCtrl', function() {
  console.log('List');
})
```

## login.html

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="usr">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" ng-model="name">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" ng-model="password">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="checkLogin()">Login</button>
<p ng-model="message"></p>
```

Comment: Can you expand on *"$scope/controller not working"*? That doesn't tell us much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` is used with `<input`> tags to capture user input, by two way binding with your model value.

Since a `<p>` tag does not collect user input, it won't work with `ng-model`. Instead just do a one way binding with the value using the curly brackets:

```
<p>{{message}}</p>
```